# React load image dynamically from stored path to filesystem

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I´m trying to build a React image loader component that will load an avatar image of the use picture, if any. If the user has a picture its path will be stored in the database.

Normally this is the way I´m loading a image:

```
import img from '../../images/myimage.jpg'
```

and then:

```
<img alt='user' src={img} />
```

This works fine on my setup, and the image is shown on screen.

My new use case needs to receive a filesystem path:

```
class Image extends Component {

    static propTypes = { 
      fsPath: PropTypes.string,
      alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired

    };

    getImage = () => {

        if (this.props.fsPath)
            return <img alt={this.props.alt} src={this.props.fsPath}/>;

        return <p>{this.props.alt}</p>
    }

    render() {

            if ({})

            return (
                <div>
                   {this.getImage()}
                </div>
    }
};

export default Image;
```

When passing `srcPath` to the component, it does not show the image (naturally because it is not "requiring" it through webpack).

How can I make my component load the image based on the given path on my file system ?

Answer (score 0):

```
getImage = (props) => {

        if (props.fsPath)
            return <img alt={props.alt} src={props.fsPath}/>;

        return <p>{props.alt}</p>
    }

    render() {

            if ({})

            return (
                <div>
                   {this.getImage({...this.props})}
                </div>
    }
```